# Recommended way to download remote SQL server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, teamcity

I'm corrently setting up our company DTAP environment for our ASP.NET web application. Current setup is like this:

1. Dev - on local machine with local developer db
2. Test - on our local company server with local company server DB
3. Acceptance - Production machine in separate IIS application, running a copy of production db
4. Production - Production machine on production DB

I want to add another environment in order to be able to reproduce bugs related to the data in the production db. I'm deploying everything using TeamCity and I'm looking for the easiest solution to download the production database (or a backup of it) to our company server and use if for a 'test on live data' environment.

What would be the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the database on the target server - "Tasks" - "Import data".

Specify your production server/tables as the source.